# Is is legal to have relativePath to parent pom in a repository?

Tags: java, maven, ivy

I found this artifact pom in the maven 2 central repository:

http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1.2/jsp-api-2.1.2.pom

It includes:

```
...
<parent>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsp</artifactId>
  <version>2.2</version>
  <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
<artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>${jsp-api.version}</version>
<name>JavaServer Pages(TM) API v${jsp-api.version}</name>
....
```

I encountered a problem when I tried to resolve with Ivy the dependency:

```
<dependency org="javax.servlet.jsp" name="jsp-api" rev="2.1.2" />
```

Ivy could not resolve the dependency and printed out this error:

```
[ivy:resolve]       nexus: bad revision found in http://XXX/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1.2/jsp-api-2.1.2.pom: expected='2.1.2 found='${jsp-api.version}'
```

Now wonder if it is ok that a pom file in a repository references relatively to a parent pom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [POM Reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance): "Notice the relativePath element. It is not required, but may be used as a signifier to Maven to first search the path given for this project's parent, before searching the local and then remote repositories."

That effectively means that the relativePath is only used if it's found, and then Maven falls back to normal repository lookup. In this case, repository lookup should work fine, as the referenced artifact is [available in central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.glassfish.web%7Cjsp%7C2.2%7Cpom). Are you using a local repo or proxy? It could be that your proxy settings are preventing Ivy from finding the parent pom.

Comment: I am Ivy is searching through a nexus repository group (Maven Central, Java.net Repo, JBoss Repo).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is legal.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance

From the error, it looks like it's not resolving `${jsp-api.version}` for you.

Comment: I know that it is legal during development. But what about published to a repository?